# How can I write set of all positive rational numbers

Tags: cantor-set

How to write the set of all rational numbers?? From Cantor's matrix we can get the positive ones. Should I add corresponding negative values and a 0?

Comment: Very similarly to the proof showing that all integers are countable.

Comment: Yes. After writing the rational number set then I can proof by one to one correspondence that rational numbers are countable. I was confused about the set of rational numbers

Answer (score 1):

Use the order 0,1,-1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ... for the numerator and then apply the Cantor matrix.  The denominator can be called positive wlog.